# eof in perl- going in infinite loop

Tags: perl, eof

When I am checking for `eof` condition for being false, it's going in infinite loop.
Here is what I am doing.

```
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File' , "abc.txt" or die;

for (my $i=0; ; $i++) {
    # if I put if(!eof())condition instead of the below one, 
    # it goes in infinite loop.  May I know why?
    if ($lines[$i] =~ /^[\s]*hello/) {
    splice @lines, $i, 1, "#$lines[$i]", "hi";
    last;
    } 
    #Below eof condition is working
    if(eof){
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, you sure the for loop doesn't have any issues?

Comment: I guess not. Because the below eof condition is working completely fine.

Comment: And I thought it was that condition that was giving you problems?

Comment: take a look at my edited answer. I think your problem is the 2nd Condition. when you use it, you dont need to use the `eof` Part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `eof` without an argument uses the last file read. Using `eof()` with empty parentheses is very different. It refers to the pseudo file formed from the files listed on the command line and accessed via the `<>` operator.

EDIT:

Normally you dont need to use `eof`, because the input operators typically return `undef` when they run out of data, or if there was an error.

CODE:

Maybe the Problem is, that you dont use the 2nd condition of the `for` loop.

```
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File' , "abc.txt" or die;

for(my $i=0;$i<=$#lines; $i++) {
    if ($lines[$i] =~ /^[\s]*hello/){
        splice @lines, $i, 1, "#$lines[$i]", "hi";
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to give eof condition in my program, right? Else it'll go in infinite for loop.

Comment: Well, i can give you a better solution to get rid of the complete `eof` problem, when you tell me what you actually want to do.

Comment: Maybe a link to the documentation of Tie::File is all it takes. Those docs are pretty good. In fact, skimming only the SYNOPSIS should do it.

Comment: @karate_kid I have **never** used [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html "perldoc -f eof"), nor do I think there will ever come I time that I will. There may be some code where you need to use it, but most of the time it could be better written some other way.

Answer (score 1):

[`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) presents a file as an *array*, and I would be very wary of using `eof` (and `tell` and `seek` for that matter) on a tied array. The module's documentation says nothing about these functions and you shouldn't assume anything as, when you write `$lines[$i]` the data may be returned from a cache, and be completely different from the last line read from the file.

I would make use of the properties of the array, and write simply

```
last if $i == $#lines
```

which is guaranteed to work because the size of the tied array varies consistently with the number of loines in the file. In fact the whole loop could be written better by putting the test on the value of `$i` in the `for` loop, like this.

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @lines; ++$i) {
  if ($lines[$i] =~ /^[\s]*hello/) {
    splice @lines, $i, 1, "#$lines[$i]", "hi";
    last;
  } 
}
```

or, perhaps using [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'first_index';
use Tie::File;

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File' , "abc.txt" or die $!;

my $i = first_index { /^\s*hello/ } @lines;
splice @lines, $i, 1, "#$lines[$i]", "hi" if $i >= 0;
```